# a href link is not working in button of modal popup

Tags: php, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I want to redirect to some page , I gave the same link in image as well as button , but for button its not working at all .

```html
  <div class="modal fade" id="signModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body signUpPop">
         <form id="form3" name="form3" method="POST">
          <div class="row loginRow">
            <h4><?php echo $this->lang->line('Log in'); ?></h4>

            <div class="col-sm-6">
               <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>signup">  <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/sign-img.png" class="image-responsive"></a>
               <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>signup"> 
             <button  class=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('Sign Up'); ?></button>
               </a> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('Email'); ?>" id="email">
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line('password'); ?>" id="password">
              <div class="text-right">
               <!--  <span><?php echo $this->lang->line('Forgot Password'); ?></span> -->
              </div>
              <button id="login" type="button"><?php echo $this->lang->line('Log In'); ?></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried a lot but ,a href link is working for image but not for button .

```html
 <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>signup">  <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/sign-img.png" class="image-responsive"></a>


                   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>signup"> 
                 <button  class=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('Sign Up'); ?></button>
                   </a> 
                </div>
```

Can any one suggest ?

config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/techcampus';

[image]

Comment: what `href` contains for button. because above should work.

Comment: What does `base_url();` return?

Comment: its the site url , taken from config.php  @WesleyPeeters

Comment: @sradha Would you mind enclosing the config.php too?

Comment: @sradha your url returns `http://localhost/techcampus`, which won't work, since your full URL will become `http://localhost/techcampussignup`. Try adding a slash (to the end) of the path in your config file.

Comment: but its working for image a href and i added firebug snap , plz check

Comment: Can't you place the code within button, inside the parent A element, remove the 'button' element and just style the anchor link?